# Why don't Eclipse shortcut keys (CTRL + space) work?

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

When I installed Eclipse to write java programs, I found the feature of `shortcut coding (CTRL + space)` doesn't work popping up error message, giving that Eclipse version is  `Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)`

Comment: Just check your setting.Have you changed it?

Comment: Eclipse Neon is 4 years and 10 releases old, how about trying something rather more up to date.